# Click a Button from an HTML Element without ID

Tags: c#, html

How can I Click a Button from an HTML element without knowing the ID of it?

The code for the button is:-

```
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

Comment: well you need a mouse or are you meaning with javascript? or jquery? or what?

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
public void buttonClick(string type) {
    var btn = yourWeb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
             .Cast<HtmlElement>()
             .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("type") == type);
    if (btn != null)
        btn.InvokeMember("click"); 
}
```

You can call this like:

```
buttonClick("submit");
```

Comment: @user3925263:- You are welcome! But I would suggest you to edit your question so that other people can also understand your question. Also do accept this as an answer if  that helped you!

Comment: @LuisSiquot:- I will try but truly speaking that was a guess as I just concentrated on two thing 1. `C#` and 2. `Click this Button without ID` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use fizzler .net css selector engine. In that engine use the QuerySelectorAll function. Give it as a parameter button [type="submit"] instead of id, it will return all buttons, with type submit, then choose the proper one and perform click